# git diff for custom 2 files outside of any repository?

Tags: git, comparison, diff, git-diff

I need `git diff` functionality for 2 files that I have outside of any repository. Is there a way to do it? Something like `git diff --file1 /path/file1.txt --file2 /path/file2.txt` If not, what may be an alternative solution?

Answer (score 8):

The answer is right in [the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) (though I admit it's easy to miss):

> *git diff* [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>
>
>   This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem. You can omit the
>   `--no-index`
>   option when running the command in a working tree controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside the working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree controlled by Git.

Your case might fall into the "`--no-index` is optional" category, but even if it's optional you can still use it, so:

```
git diff --no-index /path/file1.txt /path/file2.txt
```

will use Git's diff.

Comment: im using v 2.21.0 and i didn't need to specify --no-index to use `git diff.` I don't use `diff` at all but I find this more useful because it gives you color output and you can also use something like this on windows as well.

Comment: @dtc: it's tough to define precisely when you *do* need `--no-index`. The point I'm making above is that you can *always* use it for this sort of case. If you don't need it, fine, but if you do need it for some rare case, and you don't use it, Git will gripe at you. Hence you might want to make an alias or something that supplies the flag so that you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: the file paths must be absolute, so to use relative paths: `git diff --no-index "$(readlink -f "file1.txt")" "$(readlink -f "file2.txt")"`

Answer (score -1):

If the two files are really outside of any Git repository, then Git effectively doesn't "know" anything about these files, and so `git diff` won't work.  But, the regular Linux `diff` command should work.  So instead of doing:

```
git diff /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt
```

do this:

```
diff /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt
```

Comment: `diff` is not `git diff`, so this answer is not helpful.

Comment: `2 files that I have outside of any repository` ... if I read correctly, this question has nothing to even do with Git.

Comment: `git diff` has more features than `diff`, for example `git diff --word-diff=color` or `git diff --patience`